# "cannot convert float infinity to integer" during drawing loglog plot from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, divide-by-zero

I need to draw some logarithmic plots from the data (values are already in logarithmic scale) however matplotlib somehow encounters infinity during preparation of loglog plot.

I believe that in is_decade function for some value which is close to 0, division by 0 occurs:

```
def is_decade(x,base=10):
    lx = math.log(x)/math.log(base)
    return lx==int(lx)
```

Any ideas how to deal with this problem ?
This is code example with my data set.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

list_x = [-0.5, -0.47979798913002014, -0.45959600806236267, -0.43939390778541565, -0.41919189691543579, -0.39898988604545593, -0.37878790497779846, -0.3585858941078186, -0.33838379383087158, -0.31818181276321411, -0.29797980189323425, -0.27777779102325439, -0.25757580995559692, -0.23737369477748871, -0.21717169880867004, -0.19696970283985138, -0.17676770687103271, -0.15656569600105286, -0.13636359572410583, -0.11616159975528717, -0.095959596335887909, -0.075757578015327454, -0.055555559694766998, -0.035353541374206543, -0.015151520259678364, 0.0050505050458014011, 0.025252530351281166, 0.045454550534486771, 0.065656572580337524, 0.08585859090089798, 0.10606060177087784, 0.1262626051902771, 0.14646460115909576, 0.16666670143604279, 0.18686869740486145, 0.20707069337368011, 0.22727270424365997, 0.24747470021247864, 0.26767680048942566, 0.28787881135940552, 0.30808079242706299, 0.32828280329704285, 0.34848481416702271, 0.36868691444396973, 0.3888888955116272, 0.40909090638160706, 0.42929288744926453, 0.44949489831924438, 0.46969699859619141, 0.48989900946617126, 0.51010102033615112, 0.53030300140380859, 0.55050510168075562, 0.57070708274841309, 0.59090912342071533, 0.6111111044883728, 0.63131308555603027, 0.65151518583297729, 0.67171722650527954, 0.69191920757293701, 0.71212118864059448, 0.73232322931289673, 0.75252532958984375, 0.77272731065750122, 0.79292929172515869, 0.81313127279281616, 0.83333331346511841, 0.85353541374206543, 0.8737373948097229, 0.89393937587738037, 0.91414141654968262, 0.93434339761734009, 0.95454549789428711, 0.97474747896194458, 0.99494951963424683, 1.0151499509811401, 1.03534996509552, 1.0555599927902222, 1.0757600069046021, 1.0959600210189819, 1.1161600351333618, 1.1363600492477417, 1.1565699577331543, 1.1767699718475342, 1.1969699859619141, 1.2171700000762939, 1.2373700141906738, 1.257580041885376, 1.2777800559997559, 1.2979799509048462, 1.3181799650192261, 1.338379979133606, 1.3585900068283081, 1.378790020942688, 1.3989900350570679, 1.4191900491714478, 1.4393899440765381, 1.4595999717712402, 1.4797999858856201, 1.5, 1.5202000141143799, 1.5404000282287598, 1.5606000423431396, 1.5808000564575195, 1.6009999513626099, 1.6211999654769897, 1.6413999795913696, 1.6615999937057495, 1.6818000078201294, 1.7020000219345093, 1.7222000360488892, 1.742400050163269, 1.7625999450683594, 1.7827999591827393, 1.8029999732971191, 1.823199987411499, 1.8434000015258789, 1.8636000156402588, 1.8838000297546387, 1.9040000438690186]
list_y = [-0.033239554613828659, -0.037707798182964325, -0.042734216898679733, -0.048379786312580109, -0.054710298776626587, -0.061796598136425018, -0.069714449346065521, -0.078544475138187408, -0.088371939957141876, -0.099286220967769623, -0.11138062179088593, -0.12475139647722244, -0.13949693739414215, -0.15571676194667816, -0.17350961267948151, -0.19297224283218384, -0.21419693529605865, -0.23726895451545715, -0.26226347684860229, -0.28924143314361572, -0.31824567914009094, -0.34929537773132324, -0.38237985968589783, -0.41745156049728394, -0.4544181227684021, -0.49313366413116455, -0.5333896279335022, -0.57490617036819458, -0.61732500791549683, -0.66020554304122925, -0.70302659273147583, -0.74519622325897217, -0.78607243299484253, -0.82499557733535767, -0.86133092641830444, -0.89451992511749268, -0.92412877082824707, -0.94988745450973511, -0.97171056270599365, -0.98969388008117676, -1.0040895938873291, -1.0152649879455566, -1.0236542224884033, -1.0297127962112427, -1.0338805913925171, -1.0365564823150635, -1.0380839109420776, -1.0387473106384277, -1.0387735366821289, -1.0383385419845581, -1.0375756025314331, -1.0365840196609497, -1.0354362726211548, -1.034185528755188, -1.0328699350357056, -1.0315178632736206, -1.0301498174667358, -1.0287811756134033, -1.0274238586425781, -1.0260865688323975, -1.0247762203216553, -1.0234981775283813, -1.0222563743591309, -1.0210539102554321, -1.0198931694030762, -1.0187755823135376, -1.0177022218704224, -1.0166736841201782, -1.0156899690628052, -1.0147509574890137, -1.0138561725616455, -1.0130050182342529, -1.0121965408325195, -1.0114297866821289, -1.0107033252716064, -1.0100163221359253, -1.0093671083450317, -1.0087541341781616, -1.0081764459609985, -1.0076324939727783, -1.0071206092834473, -1.0066394805908203, -1.0061874389648438, -1.0057634115219116, -1.0053658485412598, -1.0049934387207031, -1.0046447515487671, -1.0043183565139771, -1.0040134191513062, -1.0037285089492798, -1.0034624338150024, -1.0032142400741577, -1.0029826164245605, -1.0027667284011841, -1.0025657415390015, -1.0023785829544067, -1.0022042989730835, -1.0020421743392944, -1.0018914937973022, -1.0017514228820801, -1.0016212463378906, -1.0015003681182861, -1.0013881921768188, -1.0012840032577515, -1.0011874437332153, -1.0010977983474731, -1.0010148286819458, -1.000937819480896, -1.0008665323257446, -1.0008004903793335, -1.0007392168045044, -1.0006827116012573, -1.000630259513855, -1.0005817413330078, -1.0005369186401367, -1.000495433807373, -1.0004570484161377, -1.0004216432571411, -1.0003888607025146, -1.0003585815429688]

pyplot.loglog(list_x, list_y, basex=10, basey=10)
```

Comment: It should have complained for the negative values first. You can't take log of a negative number.

Comment: I should have seen that it evaluates log from my data, but if loglog calculates log from data and my data is already in log scale, how to draw it with log scale on axes?

Comment: Ah you have log(x) as list_x. loglog takes x, not log(x). Either do a normal plot with adjusted tick labels, or convert your data back and do loglog plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is negative, for a loglog plot it has to be positive.